# How can I make my icon and anchor tag into one clickable text?

Tags: html, font-awesome

I am trying to take the icon I got from FontAwesome and make it into one piece of text with the word 'Contribute'. Currently they are separate when hovered over.

`<a class="contribute" href="#">Contribute</a><i class="fas fa-comments"></i>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your Font Awesome icon is not inside your `<a>` element:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<a class="contribute" href="#">Contribute<i class="fas fa-comments"></i></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, problem half solved. When I hover over the icon it acts as if the text and icon are in one but when I just hover over the 'contribute' text, it doesn't change the hover color of the icon.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have different CSS that is affecting this? If so, please post it.

Comment: I did have CSS affecting it, your original answer fixed the problem.